# Can you say that something "eats time"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a more expressive way to say that something takes time/delays something important. Does the following expression make sense in English?

*a tech glitch that eats time* (of an important meeting, for instance)

Comment: I'm a native English speaker.  A few minutes ago I literally said, "Wow, that really eats a lot of my free time every day." to a co-worker.

Comment: @HotLicks You should leave that as an answer itself, rather than answering in comments :)

Comment: You'd probably say "eats up time".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The more idiomatic way to say it is that it **eats up** time:

> An example of eat used as a verb is to say that something eats up time meaning it takes a lot of time.
>   <sub>[Your Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/eat)</sub>

Here's an example:

> With manual methods, answering these questions is a Herculean task that eats up time better spent on other projects.
>   <sub>[Dell Software — Enterprise Reporter](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/enterprise-reporter-datasheet-26611.pdf)</sub>

Comment: abs ’the collocation I’m used to seeing is ***eats up a lot of time***

Comment: Yeah, you don't really have to get into chewing and digestion to use _eat up_ -- it just means 'use too much of', whether it's something real, like paint (_That sprayer eats up the paint too fast_) or something imaginary, like time being exchanged for some experience in the [_`Time Is Money`_ metaphor theme](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf).

Comment: I also often see "It's eating up a lot of my time" when talking about something that's currently occuring

Comment: I've also heard (and used) _into_ used as an alternative to _up_. **"I had to tell my boss the project is eating into time I should be spending with my kids."** [Also referenced here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/eat-into).

Comment: Bear in mind that "eating into" is only really appropriate when you have another specific block of time that is being reduced (eaten into) by the expansion of the first block. i.e. the time with your kids in your example.